# Why can't I edit on Meta?

Tags: support, editing, meta

I've noticed that no posts (questions *or* answers) on Meta have a link to edit them. I highly doubt every single one I've looked at has a pending edit, so why can't I edit any of them?

**EDIT:** Apparently I am able to edit my own posts (good thing, had a pretty blatant typo in the title).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging around on various Meta sites, I found a link on SuperUser's Meta to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97371/167443).

To summarize:

> Mostly because the per-site metas are generally low traffic -- some of them count daily visits in the dozens.
>
> That means the moderators will have to do the work, since the 10k site users are the only ones that can even see this queue. And on many sites, like say Bicycles -- there are exactly zero users at this rep level, even after many months.

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/78319/167443), not allowing suggested edits on meta sites is by design.

Comment: I see, but I don't understand it. What's the difference with allowing it like on the main site, since the rep is the same? Makes no sense, as most decisions around here.

Comment: The main site gets much more traffic than Meta, so the edit queue is more likely to be handled in a shorter time (still seems to me to take a longer on this site than others)

Comment: Fine, it would be longer. So...?

Comment: BTW it _wouldn't_ be longer, since less users --> less edits. As much as less users --> less edit reviewers.

Comment: Fewer users might mean fewer edits, but the decision was made to prevent all the work of approving/rejecting edits from falling solely on moderators.

Comment: Still doesn't compute. It would be just like on the main site, only with both less edits _and_ less users able to approve them. Unless there is data showing the "users able to approve them" decrease much more than the edits themselves, it makes no sense.

Comment: There are no pending edits on this meta site, though.

Comment: @Tetrad that's because suggested edits are not allowed

Comment: Oh, well your link didn't explicitly point to the question where they said this is "by design".  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78223/per-site-metas-dont-have-ability-of-suggested-edits/78319#78319

Comment: I will add that link.

Comment: Notably, if a post is Community Wiki (a checkbox just below the post-input box) then anyone can edit. This is part of why some really important discussion posts (such as FAQ editing) are CW in meta -- to allow any user to edit the post!